# bpftrace tracepoint:syscalls:sys_enter_getcwd can't capture my user process

Tags: bpf, bpftrace

I am learning bpftrace. I am trying to capture getcwd syscall when I run cwd command, but there is no result.

```
bpftrace -e 'tracepoint:syscalls:sys_enter_getcwd {printf("called, command %s, process_id %d\n", comm, pid);}'
```

However, if I run strace pwd, I get the result. Why?